# How to redirect to specific route on dialog dismiss in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog

I created a form that once submitted shows a dialog to the user, like this:

```
         .....
          showDialog(
            barrierDismissible: false,
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                content: Container(
                  child: Wrap(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(gradient: linearGradientCustom),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                             .....
```

I am not using any button or icon to close the dialog, since the dialog box is quite small and it just makes sense to simply tap away from it to dismiss it.

The issue is that I need to redirect the users to a different route on dismiss, instead of simply popping the dialog context.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.then` like this

```
   await showDialog( 
   ....//Your Dialog Code 
).then((val){ 
    // reditect to specific route 
 });
```

Comment: Hello and thank you. I'm not using async in the function so I tried to add it without await but it doesn't work. It doesn't redirect and it doesn't get dismissed when clicking out of it. Any clue?

Comment: It doesn't get dismissed because of this line `barrierDismissible: false`. Please remove it.